# Angular 2 assigning class variable to results

Tags: angular

I can not figure how this will log to the console in my `getProfile()` method but if I assign `this.user` to user It will not return my json object.

So if I do:

```
getProfile() {
    this.userService.getPortInfo()
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
        });
}
```

That will log to the console.
But if I do:

```
getProfile() {
    this.userService.getPortInfo()
        .then(user => {
            this.user = user;
        });
}
```

and try to console.log this.user anywhere it returns an empty array. My goal is to assign this.user to my results of getProfile() and use it in my view. Not necessarily log it out.

Forgive me for my description with this issue I am fairly new to angular.

```
export class UserService {

/**
 *
 * @param http
 */
constructor(public http: Http) {
}

getPortInfo() {
    return this.http.get(environment.api)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * @returns {ErrorObservable<T>}
 */
private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

}

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

user: User[] = [];

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
}

getProfile() {
    this.userService.getPortInfo()
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfile();

    console.log(this.user);
}

_setUser(user) {
    return this.user = user;
}
```

}

Comment: you forgot to `return this.user`

Comment: This does not work either: getProfile() {
        this.userService.getPortInfo()
            .then(user => {
                return this.user = user;
            });
    }

Comment: try and use a observable and then subscribe to the result that is the way angular2 tells you to do , ut better than promise in many ways . get an observable from the service and subscribe it in the class you want to use it.

Comment: Why do you complicate things? call all your sub functions inside ngOnInit after the "then" statement... that is the only time the user is ready to be consumed, because as already said in answers, it is an asynchronous call

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPortInfo()` method is asynchronous (it returns the promise), and javascript compiler doesn't wait for the result of the promise, it'll just run the next lines of code (in your case - that's the `console.log()`.

The correct way of doing this is to return Promise from `getProfile()` method:

```
getProfile() {
    return this.userService.getPortInfo()
        .then(user => this.user = user);
}
```

and in `ngOnInit()` use `.then` to call `console.log()` only after Promise resolves:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getProfile()
       .then(() => console.log(this.user));
}
```

That way `console.log()` will run only after we get the results from Promise.

Comment: core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined:     ngOnInit() {
        this.getProfile().then(() => console.log(this.user));
    }

Comment: @GrassRoot can you provide a minimal working plunker to test your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would instead suggest you to use the **rxjs/do** operator which will be as below

First Include Import

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
```

Then modify your code like

```
getProfile(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.userService.getPortInfo()
        .then(user => {this.user = user;})
            .do(data => console.log("user data " + user))
                .catch(this.handleError);

    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
            console.log(error);
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Internal Server error');
    }
```